# Angular JS v 1.4.8 , cannot access object element with integer index

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, parse-error

I have a object defined like in controller

```
$scope.daysPerWeekModel = {'256': false, '128': false, '64': false, '32': false, '16': false, '8': false, '4': false};
```

And I want to access this in view like following way

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="daysPerWeekModel.4" ng-change="toggleTimePerWeek(16);"/>
```

but I getting a parse error like

Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/syntax?p0=.4&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=17&p3=daysPerWeekModel.4&p4=.4

My Angular version is 1.4.8.

Comment: `ng-model="daysPerWeekModel['4']"`

Answer (score 0):

You should access it using array index.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="daysPerWeekModel['4']" ng-change="toggleTimePerWeek(16)"/>
```